# Prevent dramatic conflicts before file moving

Tags: git

I have to move files around to different directories on one branch and in the mean time on the other branch, changes are being made on the files in the old directories. How do I prevent nasty conflicts before I merge these two branches together in git? Or how can I preserve the changes so when the first branch is merged in first, I could know what changes to bring to the latest master - the changes that's done on the second branch.

Comment: Are you moving files **and** editing them in the one branch? If not, Git should be able to follow renames.

Comment: Different branches. Same set of files.

Comment: Git should follow the rename in one branch when merging the files in from another

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you.